# Some content of my page doesn't display when I scroll to the right.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I'm using datatables to display data on a normal html page, but for some reason some of the content (body) of the table as well as the background of the page and the header of the table don't get displayed. I started noticed that when I added the overflow-x=true and scrolled the page to the right, here's an screenshot of the page when I scroll to the right hand side of the page: 
http://postimg.org/image/y06xyb6o3/

The code that I'm using is the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/xF8hZ/172/

This is what I added to my css file so I could scroll to the right:

```
body.ui-mobile-viewport, div.ui-mobile-viewport
{
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: I am not seeing this issue in chrome Version 40.0.2214.115 m (64-bit) on win 7

Comment: Are you talking about the JSFiddle or you actually ran it in your localhost machine?

Comment: in the fiddle you provided

Comment: I see it fine in the fiddle I provided but not on my machine. I just provided the Fiddle as a way to show my code but the problem that I  having is in my localhost. That's why I posted the image about it.